# Workout effectiveness

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, rest, sets, reps

It's my 3rd week going to gym. I'm 24 y.o. 87kg, 172cm male. Previously I only did some pull-up and dips. It's 3 times a week

```
1st day - chest, shoulders, biceps 
2nd day - back, triceps
3rd day - legs
```

The problem is I don't feel tired the next day after the training starting from the 2nd week, while I felt exceptionally tired during every day of the 1st week, and a lot of people say that this means my workout is not effective. I do increase weights and perform set almost till failure though (resting no more than 2 min between sets). For example on the 1st week I was doing bench press with 50kg, 2nd week - 65kg, and 3rd - 70kg, 3 sets of 12 and I could only do 7-10 reps in 4rd and 5th sets. 
It it okay to not feel tired after the effective workout? Or do I need to change the routine?

Comment: Don't focus so much on being tired, it's not important. I would switch days for biceps and triceps though, or is there a special reason why you have back and triceps on the same day? Most people combine back en biceps because of rows, and chest and triceps for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do I need to change the routine?**

**No**. So long you are able to **progress in weights / reps / sets**, you do not need to change your routine. With that said, this is called progressive overload. So long you are progressing, your workout is pretty much effective for you. You are doing pretty well except for your 3rd week. So what you could do is continue doing 70 kg and achieve your 5 sets of 12.

However, I don't think you need that much set since your pretty much doing high amount of reps.

**Is it okay to not feel tired after the effective workout?**

**Absolutely alright**. If you feel fatigue, be it physical and/or nervous fatigue, its not a good thing. Depending on your genetics, it may take up to **24 - 48 hours to recover from physical fatigue**(it may even take a longer time or even a shorter time).

But its a different case for nervous fatigue (also known as [central nervous system fatigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_nervous_system_fatigue)). Unlike physical fatigue, if you continue to lift heavy everyday, you may experience the following symptoms which are related to nervous fatigue :-

• Depression

• Decrease in training capacity / intensity

• Washed-out feeling, tired, drained, lack of energy

And more can be found [here](http://www.tabatatimes.com/overtraining-syndrome-and-cns-fatigue/).

To avoid facing neural fatigue, try **alternating between a light training session and a heavy training session**. For example, you go heavy on your chest, shoulders, biceps and go light for your back, triceps. Increasing your caloric intake and your rest will also help.

With that said, since you are **training 3 times a week**, **you should be fine**.